# Make columns and rows mandatory

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, worksheet

i need to make rows and columns mandatory before close

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim r As Long

'   Activate correct sheet
'   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'   Find last row in column A with data
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
'   Loop through all rows with data in column A
    For r = 2 To lr
'       Check to see if column A is not zero
        If Cells(r, "A") <> 0 Then
'           Check to see that columns B and C are not empty
            If Cells(r, "B") = "" Or Cells(r, "C") = "" Then
                Cancel = True
                MsgBox "Please fill in columns B and C", vbOKOnly, "ROW " & r & " INCOMPLETE!!!"
            End If
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: I tested your code as is... It does exactly what you're asking it to... It's a fine bit of code. You could make it a bit faster by pulling everything into as array, and make it a bit more user friendly by only returning 1 msgbox with a list of lines missing data. but it all seems to work.

Comment: This is missing an error description as well as a question and a description of what you expect your code to do. Note that this peace of code is located in the scope of `ThisWorkbook` which means `Cells` without specifying a worksheet points to the active sheet. Instead I recommend to define which sheet this should refer to: `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` and then using `ws` for every `Cells` object like `lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and accordingly for all the others in this peace of code. Otherwise there is the cance Excel is picking the wrong sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I made it a bit faster and more user friendly using:

- Arrays to iterate data.
- a single error message at the end rather than several.
  I also made the requested change to allow code to work with and column width requirements. Just change the `ColumnsToCheck = 6` to however many columns.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim ColumnsToCheck As Long
    Dim MissedItem As Boolean
    Dim Mitem As Boolean
    Dim M As Long
    Dim SrcRG As Range
    Dim SrcArr
    Dim OutMessage As String
    
    ' *** This is the number of columns you are checking INCLUDING Column A
    ColumnsToCheck = 6  'Minimum = 2

'   Find last row in column A with data
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set SrcRG = Range("A1").Resize(lRow, ColumnsToCheck)
    SrcArr = SrcRG
    MissedItem = False
    OutMessage = "Please fill in data columns 2 through " & ColumnsToCheck & "." & vbCrLf & _
                "Missing Data found in the following locations." & vbCrLf
                
    
'   Loop through all rows with data in column A
    For I = 2 To lRow
'       Check to see if column A is not zero
        If SrcArr(I, 1) <> 0 Then
'           Check to see that columns B and C are not empty
            For M = 2 To ColumnsToCheck
                Debug.Print SrcArr(I, M)
                If SrcArr(I, M) = "" Then Mitem = True
            Next M
            If Mitem = True Then
                MissedItem = True
                OutMessage = OutMessage & vbCrLf & _
                            " Missing data at row # " & I
                Mitem = False
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    
    If MissedItem = True Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox OutMessage, vbOKOnly, "Error: Missing Data"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

[image: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it just comes for two cloumns B and C but i need like more till F

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Cameron i got that

Comment: I edited the code to be able to handle any number of columns.